# Magento checkout - getting custom attribute value

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout, controllers

I am working in the OnepageController.php

What I needed was in the checkout process was to get values of some customer created attributes for the products in the current order. I have been able to get the system attribute 'sku' to show but I can't get custom attribute values to show.

My code so far is:

```
    $helper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
    $items = $helper->getCart()->getItems();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemSku = $item->getSku();

        echo $itemSku."<br/>";
  }
```

I have ran this in FireFox using Firebug and it does display the SKU value. What I need however is the value of a custom attribute created in the backend. I have tried to replace:

```
$itemSku = $item->getSku();
```

to:

```
$itemEan = $item->getAttributeText('ean');
```

Where 'ean' is the attribute identifier. This attribute is a text field. When the checkout is ran again there are no errors but noting displayed (apart from the break line html tag).

I also have another custom attribute which is a 'multi-select' attribute. Does how we get the attribute value for this change?

Any help displaying this is much appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

I can't write an answer because of no reputation but I have found a solution which works for me if it helps anyone. The code below worked for me:

```
    $cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()-getAllItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        $ean = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getEan();
        echo $ean;
    }
```

where 'getEan()' is the name of my custom attribute starting with a capital letter.

Thanks to all for their input.

Comment: sorry unable to comment and hence putting my thought in the answer. Have you tried print_r($item) to see if it has ean in it? and if yes, what is the value?

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried it but I got such a big array it wouldn't load in my browser. I have managed to get it to work with my answer below.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to make an answer but the code I used is below. I will update the answer properly when I the site lets me.

Comment: $cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()-getAllItems();
  foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
   $ean = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getEan();
   echo $ean;
  }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some research I managed to find some code which helped, which is below:

```
    $cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
          ->getQuote()
          ->getAllItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        $ean = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getEan();
        echo $ean;
    }
```

Where getEan is the name of my attribute with the first character as a capital letter.

Thank you all for the suggestions.

Comment: You want to add the attribute to the attribute list which is loaded and then remove the damn `load()` inside the loop! http://www.atwix.com/magento/accessing-custom-attribute-at-checkout-or-cart/ see the config.xml snippet!

Answer (score 7):

add this to your module's config.xml:

```
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <attribute1 />
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
```

You will be able to access the attribute through:

```
$_item->getProduct()->getData("custom_attribute");
```

Comment: From performance perspective best method so far : https://www.atwix.com/magento/accessing-custom-attribute-at-checkout-or-cart/

Answer (score 4):

If you are in product page, then for drop-down attribute simply add

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code');
```

for text attribute add

```
echo  $_product->getData('attribute_code');
```

If you are not in product page then you have to load product by product id first.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

Answer (score 2):

`getAttributeText` is for dropdown fields. For text fields use magic getters:

```
$item->getEan();
```

or

```
$item->getData('ean');
```

For your multi-select the `getData` should return an array - which you then have to foreach over, or you could implode it. If you're in a context where you don't know what type is being returned (though I'm not sure how this would even be possible) you can test it via the following:

**Get attribute object – if you only have attribute code**

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $_attribute_code);
```

**Get Multi-Select Values**

```
if($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiselect') {
  $multiSelectArray = $_product->getAttributeText($_attribute);
  #var_dump($multiSelectArray);
  echo implode(', ',$multiSelectArray);
}
```

<sup>Source: http://www.magentodeveloperleedsuk.co.uk/get-drop-down-list-and-multi-select-values-for-magento-product-attributes/</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have tried both getEan() and getData('ean') but I am still getting an empty output. Is there anything I've missed out? I'm using this code in OnepageController.php in the function: public function saveOrderAction()

Comment: var_dump the output or use join to echo. Or better yet - Mage::log the output and paste here.

Comment: If I use $itemEan = $item->getSku(); var_dump($itemEan); I get the output: string(9) "123456789" which is the sku for the product I'm testing. If I use $itemEan = $item->getData('ean'); var_dump($itemEan); what gets displayed is 'NULL'.

Answer (score 1):

On the product view as well as the checkout page and the cart page on Magento Community Edition 1.7.0.2. I managed to get my custom attribute to appear by doing this:

```
$custom_attribute = $_product->getData('custom_attribute');
```

Hope this would be of help!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I believe it's something to do with your function selection. From my understanding, if you want to show a [text] attribute, you should use getData. If you want to get a DropDown value, you should be using getAttributeText. This is how it works for me, regardless of the view. I have successfully used these two functions on PRODUCT view and checkout Page as well as the cart page. So, my answer still answers your question and I don't get why the down vote!